# jquery dynamic binding .on() select parents or children?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, binding, eventhandler

For example,

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});

$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

.on() binds "tr" with click event handler. 
The first one select children and register click event handler directly. 
The second one select parent "tbody", and select children "tr" as an argument.

Are they both dynamic binding? 
Do they have the same effect? 
What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only the second version is dynamic binding.

It should be simple to understand. When you have code like:

```
$(selector).method(arguments);
```

jQuery finds all the elements that match the `selector` at the time you execute the code, and calls the `method` on them at that time. If you execute this code when the page is first loaded, it will only find the elements that match the selector in the initial document. If the `tr` elements are added dynamically, the first version will not find them, so it will not bind the click event to them.

When you use `.on()` with a selector as the second argument, e.g.

```
$(outerSelector).on(event, innerSelector, function...);
```

it works as follows. It finds all the elements that match `outerSelector`, and binds a handler for the event to them; these elements have to exist when you call `.on()`. When the event occurs, the handler checks whether the target matches `innerSelector`, and then it executes your callback function. This is how it allows the event to work on dynamically-added elements.

So the general rule is that `outerSelector` should refer to a static element in the document, while `innerSelector` refers to the dynamic elements.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is really `dynamic`, so to speak.

The following will bind the onclick event to every `#dataTable tbody tr` on the page:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() { /*event*/ });
```

The other will bind an onclick event to every `#dataTable tbody` on the page, and the event will *only* fire if one of its clicked descendents meets the selector `tr` (see [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() { /*event*/ });
```

The second can be considered dynamic because it simulates an onclick for the specified selector, whether or not any of those elements exist at the time of binding. But technically it's an event that's attached to `#dataTable tbody`.