# jQuery on() no working properly with table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a page that dynamically builds a table.  I know when you dynamically add elements you need to you the .on() method.  I have done this in the past with live but i cant seem to get it to work.  I have a table that builds when the page is loaded with 1 row and the click works but when i run the function to add new rows nothing happens when i click on it.  Can someone please help?

here is the function

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", "a", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

This is the table created on load.

```
<table id="dataTable" width="80%" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id ="123"><a id="123" href="#">Delete</a></td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the line that the ajax call adds to the table

```
var addRow = "<tr id="+id+"><td><a href='#' id="+id+" class='rowDel'>Delete</a></td><td>"+fName+"</td><td>"+lName+"</td></tr>";
$("#dataTable").append(addRow);
```

Any idea why it wouldnt be working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr a", function() { ... });
```

See [jquery dynamic binding .on() select parents or children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655988/jquery-dynamic-binding-on-select-parents-or-children/25656078#25656078) for an explanation of how this works. Put simply, all the dynamic elements must be in the argument, the method should be applied to the static element.

Answer (score 4):

The target element of event delegation should be a static element:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr a", function() {
     alert("test");
});
```